# LocationListener how it's working

Tags: android

I have question about:

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, time, distance, locationListener);
```

I don't know how it's work, in this listener i have method onLocationChanged(Location location), but when listener call this method ? I have two variable, time in miliseconds and distance in meters, first variable tell when the location should be refresh, but we have second variable, and what ? Meybe it's working that, when the time(value from time variable) is gone, listener check distance between last postion and new position and if the distance between this positions is bigger than value from distance variable, listener will call onLocationChanged method. Right ? And i can use LocationListener for NETWORK_PROVIDER and for GPS_PROVIDER and it's works the same way. Right ? That this working ?

Answer (score 0):

Time is your refresh interval i.e. location is refreshed by that amount of time. distance is the minimum change in distance in order to call onLocationChanged, basically these 2 parameters kinda filter the location you want. NETWORK and GPS provider more or less work same way, GPS is more accuracte but slow and network provider is less accurate and fast. You can check the accuracy on each location object though. So you are on the right track. Also check google play services location api which can be found here: https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html

Comment: Ok, when time variable have value 10000 (10s), my location will be refresh after this time (10s), once on ten seconds, but onLocationChanged will be call when distance beetwen last and new location will be bigger than distance variable value. Yes ?

Comment: yes. And remember though, you are setting minimum time interval 10 seconds, it may take longer to refresh, this is the minimum and when both minimum time and distance is satisfied your onLocatinChanged will be called